# Three.js Scene is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to make a simple scene with some Three.js to experiment with it and i am currently having an unknown problem.

In the explorer console it keeps saying that Three.Scene() is not a constructor no matter if i import my download of Three or if i use the cdnjs.

```
import * as Three from 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.js';


let scene, camera, renderer, cube;

function init() {
    scene = new Three.Scene();
    camera = new Three.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

    renderer = new Three.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });

    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    const material = new Three.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });

    scene.background = new Three.color(FFFF);

    const geometry = new Three.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
    cube = new Three.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(cube);

    camera.position.z = 5;
}


function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

init();

window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false)


function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    cube.rotation.x += 0.1;
    cube.rotation.y += 0.1;
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

animate();
```

I actually searched for this question but the only ones who had the same problem as me were people who misspelled something or imported something wrong.

Here the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>THREE Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <script type="module" src="./code.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure Three.js supports ESM (import statement) via the CDN url?

Comment: Everyone says it can, and i had the import from a local document before and it pops the error too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The import is not correct. It should be:

> https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.module.js

`three.module.js` is the ESM build file whereas `three.js` is UMD. If you want to use ES6 import syntax in your app, you have to use the ESM version.

Comment: Perfect, that was it. Thanks for the explanation